# Normal matrix proof

Tags: matrices, analysis, proof-explanation, matrix-decomposition

I've just been shown the Spectral Theorem proof, which states $A$ is a normal matrix iff there exist a unitary matrix $U$ and a diagonal matrix $\Lambda$ such that $A = U\Lambda U^*$. Now, I've been told the following statement directly follows from the spectral theorem, but I din't understand how? The statement is; $A \in \mathbb{C}^{nxn}$ is normal iff it has n orthogonal eigenvectors? I have no idea how it directly follows, though?

Comment: you can find the eigenvectors and -values of $A$ from those of $\Lambda$ by applying the spectral theorem. Then note that $U$ is unitary.

Comment: @Thomas I know that the eigenvalues of $A$ are the entries on the diagonal of $\Lambda$, how does this help?

Answer (score 0):

$U$ being unitary means that $U^{-1} = U^* = \overline {U^T}$. That is, 
$$
U^*U = I. \tag{1}
$$

Writing this out: Let $u_1,\ldots,u_n$ be the columns of $U$. Then for all $k, l$ it holds that 
$$
0 = \overline u_k^T u_l = <u_k, u_l>, \text{ if $k \ne l$} \\
1 = \overline u_k^T u_l = <u_k, u_l>, \text{ if $k = l$}.
$$ 
This means that the $n$ columns of $U$ are orthogonal (even orthonormal).

Since the columns of $U$ are the eigenvectors of $A$, the claim follows. (The columns of $U$ are the eigenvectors of $A$ because $A = U\Lambda U^*$ is equivalent to $AU = U\Lambda$)